# Prime Number checker is not working

Tags: java, math, primes, prime-factoring

This is the code for a function that is supposed to  return true if the input is prime and returns false if it is not.

This is how I intended for it to work:  lets say that y = 7, the loop starts with n=1. Since 1(n) is less that 7(y) the loop can iterate. The program checks if y divided by n has a remainder of 0, meaning that n is a factor of y. If it is true, then it checks to see if the factor does not equal 1 or y (7), because if they dont then that means that y has more factors other than its self and 1, meaning that it is not prime, so it should automatically end the function and return false. but since 7 has only two factors, 1 and 7, and they either equal 1 or itself (y) then after the end of the loop, it should return true.

I don't understand why it isn't working.

```
    public static boolean checkIfPrime(long y) {
    for ( long n =1L; n <= y; n++) {
        if(y%n == 0) {
            if( n != 1L || n != y) { 
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `n != 1L || n != y` can only be false if `y == 1L`.

Comment: Try to initiate for with 2 and end with n<y so you just need to check y%n and return false.

Comment: @shmosel Why do you say that shmosel, I dont understand. because if y = 7 on the first iteration n = 1 so y%n = 0. and since n =1 that means that n != 1L is false meaning that (n != 1L || n != y) is also false. Is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: @Saurabh Thank you for your input, but may you offer an explanation as to why?

Comment: `(false || true) == true`

Comment: @shmosel but in the case that i described above n which is 1 also does not equal y, which is 7. so (false || false) should equal false.

Comment: `n != y` is not false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove equal to operator in n <= y. Start your loop from 2. It must be like this.  ( long n =2; n < y; n++)

Comment: Actually you could replace || by &&.

Comment: The problem was || condition.

Comment: Yea, I feel you @Bek, shmosel just helped me realize that. I was not thinking right.

Answer (score 2):

With a few optimizations the code will be like this

```
    static boolean isPrime(long n){
    long lim = (long) Math.sqrt(n);

    if(n%2 == 0 && n != 2)
        return false;

    for (int i = 3; i <= lim; i=i+2)
        if(n%i == 0)
            return false;       
    return true;
}
```

This code:

- checks if the number is even and different from 2 (all even numbers
  except 2 are compound).
- next iterates from 3 to sqrt(n), thats because to prove a number is
  prime you don't need to check all the dividers (if you don't believe
  me try, and if still don't believe use n/2 wich is enough but not the
  minimum value).
- For loop pace start from 3 and add 2 in each iteration getting only odd numbers as divder (we first checked that it wasn't an even number).

Answer (score 1):

For what you are trying to achieve, pseudo code in my opinion should look like this:

```
set a flag = true;

Loop from 2 to y-1{
    if(y%n==0){   
        flag = false
        break; // Very important
    }
}

check flag condition & return (if some othe computation is required) or just return flag
```

if( n != 1L || n != y) : is adding a check condition unnecessarily to every iteration. try to avoid it.

Why use a flag instead of direct return statement ? Just a preference, a direct return definitely would work in this case.

Comment: Ahh I really like your method and I appreciate the input. Do you have any idea as to what is wrong with mine. I understand it is not the best, but I am trying to understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: in your initial version problem was, you initialized it with one, every long%1 will give you == 0,
Once you corrected that it would have worked mostly but failed due to the loop end condition n <= y, which will always get to true in the end and return you a false. I suggest going through Prime Number conditions once ( its a function defined on non zero integers only which should also get taken care of i think in the code.